# How to test xamarin forms ios application without apple developer account?

Tags: xamarin.forms

Hi I have created a xamrin forms application.I want to send the ios application to my friend at some other place. I dont have any apple developer account. How can I send him the app for testing? I done many searches. I just got confused.Any suggestions will be very helpfull.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to have an Apple Developer account if you want to use Test Flight or any other Apple Distribution platform.

More info on distributing Xamarin apps via TestFlight: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/deploy-test/testflight?tabs=macos

Comment: I've been through the process of testing and publishing iOS apps and can try to help you with any questions or issues.

Comment: Bro ,Thanks for the advice.